# A program to check the age of a movie attendee (C# Yellow Book excersize)

Tags: c#, beginner, object-oriented

I am currently working through the C# Yellow Book, as a first step in self directed learning. I'm supplementing that with C#8 In a Nutshell, and general searches of the Microsoft C# language references, StackOverflow etc. Working from multiple sources, however, results in sometimes conflicting coding best practices.

I do have a background in industrial programming (ladder logic, function-block programming etc), so I'm thankfully not starting from scratch regarding logical thinking. Unfortunately, this doesn't translate into knowledge of best practices and conventions in an object-orriented language.

Below is my first attempt at a program that implements objects and multiple method levels. It is based on the exercise from the Yellow Book course to implement a program that allows a user to select a movie, and then check if they are old enough to attend, though I have increased the scope somewhat to match where I am in the textbook and my own coding comfort level.

It is 428 lines, including comments, method summaries and white space (and one commented out code block I kept as refference to compare to a Visual IDE recomended change that I don't fully understand); 1 class object with 2 member variables and 5 methods; and 8 static methods.

The code does work as intended, with limitations mentioned in header comment.

To anyone willing to slog through and have a look:
-I'm looking for general feedback on conventions rather than specific code implementations, though any input is greatly appreciated!
-This is my first time using the "///" comment blocks. I would love feedback on whether I should be more or less descriptive in these.
-I realize in this implementation, use of a class object may be a bit over the top, however that was the key item I wanted to practice.
-If anyone is wanting to try and compile and test the code: the age limits are based on UK film ratings. U, 12A, 15 and 18 are implemented.

Cheers,

~NomadicAquatic

The code:

```
/* Future improvements:
 * 1) Define maximum film title length as a global constant
 *   a) Would impact: Class Film, DisplayNowShowing() column width, GenerateNowShowingArray();
 * 2) Define as external global constant the acceptabe age limits, and their assosciated numeric age limit to allow for implementation in regions with different classification systems.
 *   a) Would impact: Film.InputAge(), GenerateNowShowingArray(),
 * 3) Define maximum films showing as external global constant
 *   a) Would impact GenerateNowShowingFile()
 * 4) Create adjustable filepath.
 * 5) Backup NowShowing.txt before deletion
 * 6) Implement password check for admin ChooseMovie() break.
 * 7) Refactor movieList array to be indexed from 1, to remove need to subtract 1 from all uses of the array.
 * 8) Rebuild administrative function to allow editing of currently showing movies, rather than strictly rebuilding every time from scratch.
 * 9) GUI
 */

using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;

/// <summary>
/// A program to manage checking if a guest is old enough to attend a movie.
/// Stores current movies showing in a file NowShowing.txt, located in the same dirrectory as the program.
/// Allows system administrator to generate a new list of movies.
/// </summary>
class MovieAgeCheck
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Class of type 'Film'
    /// Used during the generation of the NowShowing.txt file, and generating a working array of the current films.
    /// </summary>
    class Film
    {
        //constants local to class
        private readonly int maxFilmLength = 30;    //Maximum characters in the film title. If changed, also change in DisplayFilmList() WriteLine column width.
        private readonly char[] forbidinText = new char[] { '*' };  //'*' banned due to use in file system.
        //key members
        private string filmName;
        private string ageLimit;

        //Functions relating to the initialization of the class members.
        /// <summary>
        /// Method to assign a film title to Film.filmName. 
        /// </summary>
        public void InputName()
        {
            string inputString;
            do
            {
                Console.Write("Please enter film name: ");
                inputString = Console.ReadLine().Trim();

                string inputStringTest = inputString;
                foreach (char f in forbidinText)
                {

                    foreach (char c in inputStringTest)
                    {
                        if (c == f)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine($"You have entered a forbidin character: {f}");
                            inputString = "";
                            break;
                        };
                    };
                }
                if (inputString.Length > maxFilmLength)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"The maximum film title lenght is {maxFilmLength} characters.");
                    inputString = "";
                }
            } while (inputString == "");
            filmName = inputString;
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Method to assign a film age rating to Film.ageLimit.
        /// </summary>
        public void InputFilmAge()
        {
            string inputString;
            bool inputValid = false;

            do
            {
                Console.Write($"Please enter the age restriction for {filmName}: ");
                inputString = Console.ReadLine().Trim().ToUpper();
                switch (inputString)
                {
                    case "U":
                    case "12A":
                    case "15":
                    case "18":
                        inputValid = true;
                        break;
                    default:
                        Console.WriteLine($"{inputString} is an invalid age restriction. Valid age restrictions are:");
                        Console.WriteLine("\"U\" (Unrestricted), 12A (12 unless accompanied by parent), 15, or 18.");
                        break;
                }
            } while (!inputValid);
            ageLimit = inputString;
        }
        
        //funcions relating to the accessing of class members.
        /// <summary>
        /// Returns Film.filmName. Will throw exception if filmName is not innitialized.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>string Film.filmName</returns>
        public string FilmName()
        {
            if (filmName == null)
            {
                throw new Exception("Attempted to access an uninitialized film name.");
            }
            return filmName;
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Returns Film.ageLimit. Will throw exception if ageLimit not innitialized.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>string Film.ageLimit</returns>
        public string AgeLimit()
        {
            if (ageLimit == null)
            {
                throw new Exception("Attempted to access an uninitialized age restriction.");
            }
            return ageLimit;
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Function to obtain derived string containing both FilmName and AgeLimit, separated by '*' character.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>string in form "filmName*ageLimit"</returns>
        public string FilmStorageString()
        {
            string film;
            film = FilmName() + "*" + AgeLimit();
            return film;
        }

    }
    
    /// <summary>
    /// Method to run the program initialization sequence.
    /// Checks for existing film list file, if none immediatelly begin generation method.
    /// Prints current film list to screen, asks user to confirm, regenerate, or terminate program.
    /// If file does not contain appropriate strings, catches exception from method GenerateNowShowingArray, and terminates program.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="shutdown">If true, terminates program</param>
    /// <returns>string["Film Title","Age limit"]</returns>
    static string[,] InitializeAgeCheck(out bool shutdown)
    {
        string[,] nowShowingArray;
        do
        { 
            if (!File.Exists(@"NowShowing.txt")) CreateNowShowingFile();
            try
            {
                nowShowingArray = GenerateNowShowingArray();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid NowShowing.txt\nPlease contact system administrator.");
                shutdown = true;
                return null;
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Currently showing:");
            DisplayNowShowing(nowShowingArray);
        }while(!RegenerateList(out shutdown));
        
        Console.Clear();
        return nowShowingArray;
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Prompt for admin to begin user program sequence, regenerate now showing NowShowing.txt file, or shutdown system.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="shutdown">If true, terminates program</param>
    /// <returns>TRUE to begin main program, otherwise returns FALSE</returns>
    static bool RegenerateList(out bool shutdown)
    {
        
        char choose;
        do
        {
            Console.Write("Would you like to use this list of movies ('U'), create a new list('N'), or Shutdown('S')? ");
            choose = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper()[0];
            if (choose == 'N')
            {
                string confirm;
                Console.Write("Are you sure you want to delete the current file and generate a new list?\nType 'delete' to continue:");
                confirm = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();
                if (confirm == "delete")    //string to confirm deletion. Change prompt above if string chaged.
                {
                    File.Delete(@"NowShowing.txt");
                }
                else choose = ' '; //assignes char other than 'U','N', or 'S' to ensure reloop of outer do..while loop.
            }
            shutdown = choose == 'S';
        } while (choose != 'U' && choose != 'N' && choose != 'S');
        
        return choose == 'U';
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Itterates through entire link of working string to display currently active film list.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="list">string["Film Title","Age limit"]</param>
    static void DisplayNowShowing(string[,] list)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < list.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{i + 1,1}:{list[i, 0],-30}{list[i, 1]}");
        }

    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Reads NowShowing.txt and converts to a two dimensional string array
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>string[,] in form [FilmName,AgeLimit]</returns>
    static string[,] GenerateNowShowingArray()
    {
        var filmsList = new List<string>();
        
        
        StreamReader read = new StreamReader($"NowShowing.txt");
        int currentLine = 0;
        while (!read.EndOfStream)
        {
            string line = read.ReadLine();
            filmsList.Add(line);
            currentLine++;
        }
        var filmsArray = new string[filmsList.Count,2];
        //Splits raw string from file at character '*'
        for (int i = 0; i < filmsList.Count; i++)
        {
            filmsArray[i,0] = filmsList[i].Split('*')[0];
            filmsArray[i,1] = filmsList[i].Split('*')[1];
            if (filmsArray[i,0].Length > 30)
            {
                throw new Exception("Invalid NowShowing.txt");
            }
            switch (filmsArray[i,1])
            {
                case "U":
                case "12A":
                case "15":
                case "18":
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new Exception("Invalid NowShowing.txt");
            }
        }
        read.Close();
        return filmsArray;
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Walk administrator through creation of a new NowShowing.txt
    /// Contains const to limit number of films showing.
    /// </summary>
    static void CreateNowShowingFile()
    {
        var films = new List<Film>();
        const int maxFilmsShowing = 15;
        const char breakChar = '#';
        
        Console.Clear();
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter the films currently showing.");
        Console.WriteLine($"The maximum number of films is {maxFilmsShowing}.");
        Console.WriteLine($"Enter {breakChar} to finish.");
        for (int i = 0; i < maxFilmsShowing; i++)
        {
            Film f = new Film();

            Console.WriteLine($"Film {i+1}: ({breakChar} to end)");
            f.InputName();
                if (f.FilmName()[0] == breakChar) break;
            f.InputFilmAge();
            films.Add(f);
        }
        
        StreamWriter write = new StreamWriter(@"NowShowing.txt");
        for (int i = 0; i < films.Count; i++)
        {
            write.WriteLine(films[i].FilmStorageString());
        }
        write.Close();
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// User selects film from displayed list of currently showing films.
    /// Entering "*admin" will leave method and reenter initialization method.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="list">string[,] in format [FilmName,AgeLimit]</param>
    /// <param name="kill">when true will exit user interface method</param>
    /// <returns>int user film selection index</returns>
    static int ChooseMovie(in string[,] list, out bool kill)
    {
        int movieSelection  = 0;
        do
        {
            kill = false;
            Console.Write("Please enter the number of the film you wish to see: ");
            try
            {
                string input = Console.ReadLine().Trim().ToLower();
                if (input == "*admin")
                {
                    kill = true;
                    return movieSelection = 0;
                }
                movieSelection = int.Parse(input);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Please enter numbers only.");
            }
            
            if (movieSelection > list.GetLength(0) || movieSelection <= 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Please enter a movie selection betwee 1 and {list.GetLength(0)}");
            }
        } while (movieSelection <=0 || movieSelection > list.GetLength(0));

        return movieSelection;
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Checks user entered age against classification of film selected
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="list">string[,] in format [FilmName,AgeLimit]</param>
    /// <param name="selection"></param>
    static void ConfirmAge(string[,] list, int selection)
    {
        const int maxAge = 125; //This is the maximum user enterable age.
        var ageLimit = (list[selection - 1, 1]) switch
        {
            "U" => 0,
            "12A" => 12,
            "15" => 15,
            "18" => 18,
            _ => throw new Exception("Something has gone wrong with the list of movies. Please contact staff"),
        };

        //No need for explicit check for Unrestricted rated movie. Immediatelly return from method.
        if(ageLimit == 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"The film {list[selection - 1, 0]} is suitable for all ages!\nPlease enjoy the show!");
            return;
        }

        int userAge;
        do
        {
            Console.Write("Please enter your age: ");
            try
            {
                userAge = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine().Trim());
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Please enter numbers only.");
                userAge = -1;
            }
        } while (userAge <= 0 || userAge > maxAge);
        
        if(userAge < ageLimit)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"I'm sorry, you are to yougn to see {list[selection - 1, 0]}.\nPlease select a different movie to watch today.");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Please enjoy today's showing of {list[selection - 1, 0]}!");
        }

    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Primary user facing method. Displayes currently showing films using DisplayNowShowing(). Calls ChooseMovie() and ConfirmAge() for user prompts.
    /// Pauses after each user awaiting any key, then clears console and repeats.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="moviesList">string[,] in format [FilmName,AgeLimit]</param>
    static void CheckAges(in string[,] moviesList)
    {
        bool quitChecking;

        do
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Welcome to out Multiplex.");
            Console.WriteLine("We are currently showing:");
            DisplayNowShowing(moviesList);
            int selectedMovie = ChooseMovie(moviesList, out quitChecking);
            if (quitChecking) break;
            ConfirmAge(moviesList, selectedMovie);
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue.");
            Console.ReadKey();
            Console.Clear();
        } while (!quitChecking);
        Console.Clear();

    }

    static void Main()
    {
         
        string[,] list;     //Working array of current films list.
        bool shutdown;      //Flag to terminate program.

        do
        {
            list = InitializeAgeCheck(out shutdown);
            if (shutdown) break;
            CheckAges(list);
        } while (!shutdown);
        Console.WriteLine("Shutting down system.");
        Console.ReadKey();
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Please remove any commented out code, it indicates that the code is not ready to be reviewed.

Comment: @pacmaninbw Commented out code removed, as it was simply for my own reference while learning so I could compare my implementation to the implementation recommended by Visual Studio IDE. Still learning StackExchange etiquette, thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Uh, the bottom line to the proceeding is at the bottom. Or, read through if you like suspense.

**C#8 In a Nutshell**

Excellent. Get an awareness of the scope of the language. Then as opportunity presents, use the book for a good overview and quick start for specific topics

---

**It is 428 lines, including comments**

Beware writing too cute or too clever code for brevity's sake.

Work very hard at making comments complement the code. Focus on the *why* of the code. Assume the reader understands C#, in this case.

---

**the "///" comment blocks**

The rich collection of tags, like `<summary>`, are intended for generating documentation, complete with links. Somewhere in MSDN there is complete explanation of this.

---

**one commented out code block**

The road to hell is paved with commented out code. This is the very big clue that it is time to use version control. IMHO everyone uses GIT because everyone uses GIT. I've found Mercurial is easer to use. There are others. But pick one and start using it. Version control allows one to be bold with experimentation, changes, and fixes.

---

---

```
        private readonly int maxFilmLength = 30;    //Maximum characters in the film title. If changed, also change in DisplayFilmList() WriteLine column width.
```

The variable name is obvious - half of the comment is not needed.

`If changed, also change` - This is a code smell (i.e. something might be wrong). Make a public getter property of/for `maxFilmLength`.

---

---

```
public class Film {
    public string FilmName() {
```

`Name()`, not `FilmName()`. It's containing class gives the context needed.

---

---

```
public string FilmName()
    {
        if (filmName == null)
        {
            throw new Exception("Attempted to access an uninitialized film name.");
        }
        return filmName;
    }
```

Set properties in a constructor. Then you'll never have to check for null. For strings prefer `String.Empty` over `null`. Because:

```
string NameNull;   // initializes to null
string NameEmpty = String.Empty;  

NameNull.Value();   // throws an exception
NameEmpty.Value();  // does not throw and exception
```

Saves exceptions for things you can do nothing about. Instead do this in a constructor:

```
 this.Name = passedInArgumentName ??  String.Empty;  // null coalesce. C# in a nutshell is your friend.
```

or at the very least:

```
  if(this.Name == null) this.Name = String.Empty;
```

Why test for null on every `Name` call when you can set it once and forget it?

---

---

**Console.WriteLine($"You have entered a forbidin character: {f}");**

Read about the `String` class in MS documentation. You'll find methods and properties that will significantly simplify string validation.

Displaying this error message without telling what is forbidden or valid is just cruel.

---

---

**What's in a name?**

```
public class MovieAgeCheck () { 
  public void InputFilmAge()
    {
        string inputString;
        bool inputValid = false;
```

`MovieAgeCheck` - 'MovieAgeRestriction `or MovieViewerRestrictions` (if it is about more than just age).  It is about viewer age restrictions, not how old the movie is.

The method name says we're getting the age of the film. `InputAgeRestriction` is better. Again, the containing class should be enough to understand we're talking about a film. If not, the method might be in the wrong class.

`inputString` - `viewerRestrictionCode` or `RestrictionCode`. It is a code being entered, not an actual age as in "happy birthday!, age.

Everything the user types is "input". "Input.." is not helpful as a variable name. As an *action* verb in the method name, that's OK.

Do not use the data type in variable names. The reader knows it's a string. **It is far more important to name things for what they are in the "film viewer age restriction" domain.**

`inputValid` - `isValid` or `isValidName`. Starting boolean names with "is" `isConvential`.

**Context, all the way down**

Given the suggested name changes:

The CLASS name tells me it is about viewing restrictions of a movie
The METHOD name tells me it is about ( movie viewing restriction, implied) age.
The VARIABLE name tells me it is about (for movie viewing restriction age, implied) code representing said restriction.

---

---

**class nesting**

Does your IDE generate a shell for `public static void Main()`?  Main should be where the movie program object(s) get instantiated and then probably a "main loop" for user prompting and results displaying.

Do not nest your classes in `MovieAgeCheck`, especially `Main`. I see no compelling reason and nesting technical detail becomes like self flagellation for the beginner.

---

---

**Group Think**

Think about code grouped into major functionality. This is the beginnings of classes and good code organization generally.

Generally, write code on a function by function basis and then call this code. Do not write pieces of like-functionality spread within long in-line code dumps.

**Possible function groups**

`Film.ToString()` - output a formatted string/lines of string, of it's own data.

The text file - create a collection of `Film` objects. The text file becomes a `string[,]`. It should be an array of `Film` objects.

Data validation - `Film` constructor calls validation for each parameter. Each film property has a corresponding validate method in the film class. User entered data will be passed to `Film` constructor. I'm imagining a public method or property for the message.

The text/data file - probably a separate class because it is a clearly different thing from `Film`s and `AgeRestrictions`. With methods to fetch from file and another to pass the plain text as Film objects. Your plans for future changes will be helped if this is an independent class.

`Film` - a basic film object: name, restriction code, validation for same.

- ToString(), returns formatted line(s) of this object's data.
- should not have to call the textFile object for anything.
- should not have to call MovieAgeCheck object for anything.

`MovieAgeCheck` - Has methods that are called in the various "main loop" places.

- `ToString()` - calls `Film.ToString()` of all Film objects, in a loop
- Does not create film objects. Film constructor does that
- Does not fetch the text file. Calls textFile object to do it.

**EDIT**

<strike>- Does not create Film objects from textFile. TextFile object passes its data to Film constructor.</strike>

- Coordinates Film object creation from textFile raw data. Asks (calls) textFile object for the `string[,]` raw data and (in a loop probably) then calls Film constructor, passing each "raw film data" element in turn.

**end Edit**

- Does not validate Film objects. Film constructor does it.
- Calls data file object method(s) to: fetch text file, return an array of Film objects.
- Calls `Film` constructor passing in user entered data

`Main` - Has the prompt-fetch-display loop.

- Instantiates a `MovieAgeCheck` object.
- Displays error messages but does not generate them.
- passes user entered data to `MovieAgeCheck`
- has loop control structure to continue entry, stop and display error message, et cetera.

---

---

Here is a rough cut

**NOTE**:  pseudocode. Do not assume this is compile-able and logically perfect.

```
public static Main() {
    MovieAgeCheck Checker = new MovieAgeCheck();

    Checker.GetMovies();  // textFile object called in here
    console.WriteLine(Checker.ToString();  // display all movies

    bool keepGoing = true;
    bool isAgeAppropriate;

    while(keepGoing) do {
        // prompt for data
        isAgeAppropriate = Checker.Validate(name, code, ...); 
      
        if(! isAgeAppropriate) {
              // whatever
              console.WriteLine(Checker.ErrorMessage());
        }
        
        //prompt to keepGoing
    }

}
```

Comment: I'm working through your amazing answer one at a time. Some makes sense, some I'm having to parse through bit by bit.

Two specific questions, possibly out of the scope of this forum:
1) If I choose a version control system now, how interchangeable are they; how easy to pivot to a different system if needed later?
2) When working through tutorial's like this as a beginner, do you feel there is more value to revisit the program and refactor it, or to move on to the next concept and exercise, and put the learning/feedback into practice on the next program?

Comment: Revisit and Refactor is always fun, because you can see how much you have learned.  revisiting and refactoring code you've written previously may give you the idea for an application that could help many people. I have a running project that I visit once in a while that I started in school. it's a game, but same concept.  if you use source control, you can see all the changes that you made from the beginning which is fun too

Comment: *If I choose a version control system now, how interchangeable are they*.  When researching, some years ago, not. But use a "distributed" model tool - Git or Mecurial. TL;DR.   Workaround Anecdote: Our Team used Subversion. I wanted my own repository for independent experimentation, subversion can't do that - it is not a "distributed" system. So happens Subversion and Mercurial metadata (buried in your source code folders) can be mutually ignored. Was not difficult to keep straight because our team versioning plan kept branching sane.

Comment: Refactoring is the active process of tweaking as you write a program. The impulse is maintaining design and structure, changing methodically as needed to facilitate new code and editing generally, while keeping and improving overall quality. The book [*Refactoring* by Martin Fowler](https://martinfowler.com/books/refactoring.html) is the seminal word on the subject. He defines many step by step "refactorings".

Comment: Pick a VC tool and learn to use it well. Forget about "what if". Available helper tools may help you choose. For example 
 TortoiseSVN for subversion and TortoiseHg for Mercurial come to mind. The Visual Studio IDE has integrate-aible tools.